# after adding a variable how to print out max and min 3 values from a column in SAS

Tags: sas

IN SAS - I was asked to add a certain variable to an XLS file and then print out max and min 3 observations of this variable (in this case Hsal). I sorted out the data by this variable, but I don't know how to print out several min/max values -

```
data SAL5; set SAL1;
Hsal=(salary/hours);
run;
proc print data=SAL5;run;

proc sort data=SAL5;by Hsal;run;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options, depending on how you want the data displayed and whether you want to show the max/min 3 observations or values (i.e. do you want to display tied values more than once or not, this won't be a problem with your data if all values are unique).

If you want the output on 1 line then using the `idgroup` statement in `proc summary` is the easiest way.

Otherwise you can take advantage of `proc univariate`, which calculates the top and bottom extreme observations or values by default.  You need to use `ods output` to create the relevant dataset, which you can then print out.  You'll probably want to restrict some of the variables from the output, which you can easily do with a `drop` statement or a `var` statement within `proc print`

I've given you all 3 options here.  If you want to show the max/min values (option 3) on 1 line then you can do a `proc transpose` after the dataset is created.  I've used `sashelp.class` as an example, just substitute age with Hsal in your data.

```
/* output on 1 line, max/min 3 observations */
proc summary data=sashelp.class nway;
output out=maxminobs1 (drop=_:) 
        idgroup (max(age) out[3] (age) = max_age)
        idgroup (min(age) out[3] (age) = min_age);
run;

proc print data=maxminobs1;
run;

/* output on 3 lines, max/min 3 observations */
ods output extremeobs = maxminobs2;
proc univariate data=sashelp.class nextrobs=3;
var age;
run;

proc print data=maxminobs2;
run;

/* output on 3 lines, max/min 3 values */
ods output extremevalues = maxminobs3;
proc univariate data=sashelp.class nextrval=3;
var age;
run;

proc print data=maxminobs3;
run;
```